# Building Play App as Docker image, remapping port

Tags: docker, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to build my Play application into a docker container thats exposed on port 8080. ie. Requests to the docker container on port 8080 hit my play application.

I'm having trouble doing this. I was thinking I could do it by either mapping Docker port 8080 to the internal port 9000, but I can't figure out how to do this with the sbt plugin. All I can do is change the exposed port using

```
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8080)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sbt-docker](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker) only builds the docker image. Exposing a port is correct, but you still have to connect it to the host network.

For that you have to start the container and provide the correct mapping.

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 ... yourImage ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. First one is to start the play app with the default port 9000 and when running your container use Docker port mapping to redirect from port 8080 outside of the container to port 9000 inside of the container:

```
docker run -p 8080:9000 yourimage
```

Option two is to to edit your `application.conf` and change the production port to be 8080:

```
# production
play.server.http.port = "8080"
```

after having done it, change the `dockerExposedPorts`:

```
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8080)
```

Note, that it will still run on port 9000 in the development mode (`activator run`).

Comment: Option two worked for me, thanks a lot! I couldn't use option one because my PaaS doesn't allow me to do port mapping.